# United Domains Redirect of PUT-Request doesn't work

Tags: redirect, azure, dns, subdomain

I have a website working on Azure and I have a domain registered at united domains. The domain redirects to azure with "URL-Hiding" (means that ud simulates the server, by having a server between the user and azure). Now I figured out, that now it's not possible to send PUT-requests. United domains delivers an error page, saying that PUT requests are not allowed on their server. 
Now how can I fix this? What I need is that mydomain.com/testpage shows xxx.azurewebsites.net/testpage, but it shouldn't redirects to it.
If the only way is not to use PUT-requests anymore, this would cause big restructuring in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use domain redirect at ISP level, rather then CNAME and A records?

You can [read more here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) on how to use your own domain with Azure Cloud Service or Storage.

And [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/), you can find the article about how to configure custom domain for Azure web sites.

I would recommend to **not** use domain redirect with Azure Services at all!